# scrollTo (bottom of scollView) not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, scroll

How do I get to refocus to the bottom of a `scrollView` after adding a view in it? I have tried different parameters in `myScrollView.scrollTo(x,y)` but none did fully work as (I) expected

```
\-- LinearLayout1 (Vertical)
     \-- Scrollview1 (Vertical)
           \-- LinearLayout2 (Vertical)
                 \-- LinearLayout3 (Vertical) (messages/smileys sent)
                 \-- ScrollView2 (Horiz)
                        \--  LinearLayout4 (Horiz) (Smileys, hidden)
                 \-- LinearLayout5 (Horiz)
                        \-- EditText1 (to enter new messages)
                     \-- Button1 (send)
                     \-- Button2 (to show/hide the smileys bar)
```

Below is my layout and the `scrollTo` code I have tried. Any idea ?
Thanks in advance...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".chat">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/messagesLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textSize="18sp">
            </LinearLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/smileysBarScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/smileysBar"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                       (images of all the smileys available here)

                    </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lowerBar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText> (message entered)
                <Button> (send...)
                <ImageView> (click to open the smiley bar)

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When the user send his message or smiley, a view is added at the bottom of messagesLinearLayout (LL3) and I call this (which I found here in an other post)

`ScrollView1.scrollTo(0, ScrollView1.getHeight());`

But it doesn't do what I want :
- when a smiley is sent (and the list of smiley goes `Visibility.GONE`) it seems to scroll only by 1 page/screen from the very top of the `ScrollView` (so for some conversations that's very far from the last message !)
- when a text is sent it does about the same (but scrolls down a tiny bit more)

I have tried other things bu none did work

```
ScrollView1.scrollTo(0, LinearLayout5.getHeight());
ScrollView1.scrollTo(0, LinearLayout5.getY());
ScrollView1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to scroll down inside handler if this will work for you

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot ! So it means the phone was not done doing the maths after adding the view (recalculating the dimensions/positions) when it started to scroll ? I think too much "sequential" I guess...

Comment: yes exactly view are in bussy calculating when scroll starts so